# Find an equation for the plane perpendicular to the line $x=5-3t, y=5t-7, z=-6t$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

The full question actually reads "At the point where $t=-1$,  find an equation for the plane perpendicular to the line $x=5-3t, y=5t-7, z=-6t$."

I'm not too sure how to use the information $t=-1$. When $t=-1, $ the line is at the point $(8,-13,6)$

I guess this means the plane has to pass through the point $(8,-13,6)$?

If that's the case, then we can read off a vector perpendicular to the line by looking at its equation. We find that $<-3,5,6>$ is perpendicular to the line, so that acts as the slope of our plane. We can turn the information we have now into a plane in normal form: $$-3(x-8)+5(y+13)+6(z-6)=0$$

which equals $$-3x + 5y +6z=53$$

But apparently the correct answer is: $$-3x + 5y +6z=120$$

I'm guessing if I went wrong anywhere, it was with my assumption of the point that the plane passes through. But I'm not sure how else to utilize the information given in the question that $t=-1$...any ideas or help is appreciated.

Edit: apologies, there was a typo in the title. I've fixed it now.

Comment: Is that supposed to be $y=4+3t$ rather than $y=4+3x$?

Comment: Your title and the line you have written in the body don't match up, not to mention both given answers are inconsistent with both sets of equations (since the perpendicular vector would really be $\langle -3, 5, -6\rangle$). Check your sources again and edit with the correct versions.

Comment: $5(-1)-7=-12$. Then, use $\vec{n}=(A, B, C) =(-3,5,-6)$ and the point $(x,y,z)=(8,-12,6)$ in the equation $$Ax+By+Cz+D=0$$ and solve for $D$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Completely by bad, $y$ is actually $5t-7$. Sorry about that, fixed now

Comment: @NinadMunshi Sorry about that, I've fixed it now. Thank you for pointing out the wrong sign on the $6$ though, I think I was getting a bit confused about how to read normal vectors off equations. Though, even that leads to a final answer of $x^2+y^2+z^2=120$

Answer (score 1):

The plane has the form

$$-3x + 5y -6z = C$$

For $t=-1$, the point on the line is $(5-3t, 5t-7, -6t)=(8,-12, 6)$. Plug it into above equation, we have

$$C = -3(8)+5(-12)-6(6)=-120$$

So, the equation of the plane is,

$$3x - 5y +6z=120 $$

Comment: Thank you! Why is it that plugging in the coordinates of the point that the plane is supposed to pass through and making the result the right hand side of the equation gives you the full equation of the plane passing through that point? My process makes more sense to me, but yours is clearly correct. I'm just not sure why. Thank you again for the help!

Comment: @JamesRonald - Your process is more explicit. It is equivalent to just plugging the point in the equation, though. The latter is implicit, but both give the same results.